# Automapper not sticking to max depth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

So, I am using ASP Core 3.1, with EF and Automapper. My API project talks with the context, while my main app consumes the API. When calling the API, i get back a 500, with a JSON error telling me I have circular references:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 
A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. 
This can either be due to a cycle or if the object 
depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
```

The code

```
public class Function
{
    public Function() {
        FunctionSkills = new List<FunctionSkill>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FunctionSkill> FunctionSkills { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Skill
{
    public Skill() {
        FunctionSkills = new List<FunctionSkill>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection <FunctionSkill> FunctionSkills { get; set; }
}
```

```
//Combined key, FunctionId, SkillId
public class FunctionSkill
{
    public int FunctionId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public virtual Function Function { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

The API produces

```
///GET:Function/Functions
var result = _context.Functions.Include(_ => _.FunctionSkills).ThenInclude(_ => _.Skill);
var mapped = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FunctionGetDTO>>(result);
return Ok(mapped);
```

The error hits when i call:

```
var result = await Http.GetAsync(Globals.ApiUrl + "Function/Functions");
var resString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<FunctionGetDTO>>(resString);
var mapres = mapper.Map<List<Data.Entities.Function>>(obj.Data.ToList());
```

Obviously, it is in the circular dependency for Function -> FunctionSkill -> Function -> .....

DTO's:

```
    public class FunctionGetDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FunctionSkill> FunctionSkills { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class SkillGetDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FunctionSkill> FunctionSkills { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
            CreateMap<Function, FunctionGetDTO>().PreserveReferences().MaxDepth(1);
            CreateMap<FunctionGetDTO, Function>().PreserveReferences().MaxDepth(1);
            CreateMap<Skill, SkillGetDTO>().PreserveReferences().MaxDepth(1);
            CreateMap<SkillGetDTO, Skill>().PreserveReferences().MaxDepth(1)
```

And still it maps indefinitly from Function -> FunctionSkill -> Function -> FunctionSkill -> ......
Any idea why?

Comment: Try `ProjectTo` instead.

Comment: Use `NewtonSoft.Json`, this is a limitation of `System.Text.Json`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Instead of?

Comment: @aguafrommars Using it already :S

Comment: So you have a configuration issue because `System.Text.Json.JsonException` aren't throwed by `NewtonSoft.Json` but by `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`